# What is the [::1] and 5353 here - resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353?

Tags: nginx

This page:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

gives this example:

```
resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353;
```

What does the `[::1]` and `:5353` mean?

Answer (score 4):

`[::1]` (or better `::1`) is the IPv6 address for [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) (`127.0.0.1` on IPv4) and `:5353` is the port number. This line tells the server to try to resolve on port `53` on `127.0.0.1` via IPv4 or on port `5353` on `::1` (localhost) via IPv6.

Comment: `::1` _is_ localhost, not just an equivalent to localhost. It is equivalent to `127.0.0.1` though.